Typescript cloud function - res not callable
I've got a cloud function as follows:
// const {onSchedule} = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler"); // The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to set up triggers and logging.
    import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";
    const {onRequest} = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');
    
    exports.dailyShiftNotification = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
        const promise = fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/messaging/dailyShiftNotification`, {
            method: 'POST',
        }).then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              logger.error("There was an error sending messages");
              return res.status(500).send('Error sending messages');
            }
            return res.json();
        }).then(result => {
            return result;
        });
        
        try {
            const result = await promise;
            console.log(result);
            return res.status(200).send('Messages sent!');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            return res.status(500).send('Error sending messages');
        }
    });

I can't return a response from my function, as res.status() this expression is not callable. Type 'Number' has no call signatures
I've tried import { Request, Response } from 'express'; and setting res: Response, req: Request which does nothing. Installing node-fetch didn't change anything. I've even just tried straight up ignoring the error with //ts-ignore. Every time, even though the function is successful, all it does is time out at the end because I can't send an actual response.

In your try block, result is the awaited promise value not res.

You're shadowing res in your first then() callback. Name it something else like response or fetchRes. Also try not to mix await with .then(), it just makes for confusing code

@DazWilkin that part isn't a problem

@Phil Wow. Thanks for pointing that out! That's what I get for staring at this for too long haha. And I'll do some cleanup to not mix await and then.

The issue you are experiencing as Phil commented is coming from the res shadowing you do with the then(). I would however change the general formatting of this and the way it is working to something like the following :)
try {
 const response = await fetch(... rest of tings) // NO THEN
 if(!response.ok) { /* error handling you were doing in then */ }

 const result = await response.json();
 return res.status(200).send('Messages sent!');
} catch (e) {
 logger.error('Error:', e);
 return res.status(500).send('Error sending messages');
}
  


Good advice, OP's error handling would have just lead to further issues

Super clean compared to the mess I had. Thanks!
